# NodeJS REST API

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I'd like to understand how to make sure that only intended clients are connecting to API server?

For example there is an end point: http://example.com/v1/api/getallcustomers

- Users will be authenticated
- Token will be issued
- Authentication will be done on every request

But I'd like to make sure only my Web and Mobile apps are connecting to this API. I would like to block/deny all other incoming connections even you know the end point. Please help. Thank you.

Cheers,

Comment: That's impossible. Anyone that knows how the API works can make a request.

Comment: That doesnt work this way. thats the reason why should ensure that only authenticated people/apps can perform opearions on your API. No (valid) token = no action.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to make sure only my Web and Mobile apps are connecting to this API. I would like to block/deny all other incoming connections even you know the end point.

That is impossible since anyone who knows how the API works and has access to a valid authentication token can make a request (using Node.js, for example). You have no way of distinguishing a request made from your app from one made from some other program.

Comment: @d-pardal Thats what i mean, if i can set them via curl/wget it's not a good way to prevent/protect anything. He has allready a good solution: Authentication with a token. And when he wants to access the API from his App he got a problem if he checks the Origin header...

Comment: The `Origin` header only protects against CSRF. I'll remove that from the answer as other websites can't find the authentication token.

Comment: @d-pardal No Cookies no CSRF: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/166724/should-i-use-csrf-protection-on-rest-api-endpoints